# How can I find a project folder in the solution?

Tags: visual-studio, search, resharper, solution

Using Visual Studio 2010 and ReSharper 7.0, there is any way to find a specific VS Project *folder* in the entire solution?

- In Visual Studio, using the **Find in Files** (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) option is only for
  files.
- In ReSharper, **Navigate To Everything** (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) is only for type members and files.

Comment: Open a folder in Visual Studio?

Comment: I want to find an existing folder.

Comment: Why do u want to do this? Do you want to find some specific word in all files within this folder?

Comment: No! I want to find a **folder**.

Comment: Could u tell me why do you want to find a folder in VS? I mean, you can easily done it in explorer.

Comment: Well,  with explorer, how would I be able to distinguish between a folder in the solution to a regular folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. It focuses to the project file which acts like a folder in the solution.

[image]

Comment: @YairNevet What's that?

Comment: What you've suggested is only available at VS 2012+. But it is anyway not what I'm looking for. To be more specific, if I was at a `*.CSPROJ` file, I was looking for something: `<Compile Include="Factory\...`

Comment: @YairNevet It should work when you write "Factory" then. It looks for folders too.

Comment: @YairNevet It's a ReSharper feature but I don't know it's avaliable in version 7.

Comment: @YairNevet You're using the Visual Studio keyboard bindings, so in your case it's `Ctrl-Shift-T`.